# When are descriptions of formal unramifiedness/smoothness via lifting properties equivalent to those via induced arrows to pullbacks?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, definitions, synthetic-differential

Formal unramifiedness of an arrow $f:M\rightarrow N$ in algebraic geometry or synthetic differential geometry in defined by asking the lifting problem below to have at most one solution (existence is not required).
$$\array{
    \mathsf{1} &\longrightarrow& M
    \\
    \downarrow &\nearrow& \downarrow
    \\
    D &\longrightarrow& N
  }$$

In SDG, I think formal unramifiedness can also defined by asking the induced arrow $TM\to P$ to the pullback below to be a monomorphism. (Recall tangent bundles are the exponentials $TM=M^D$ where $D$ is the class of zero-square "elements".)

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
    P @>>> TN\\ @VVV @VV{\pi^\prime}V\\
    M^1 @>>{f}> N^1
    \end{CD}$$

For formal smoothness, the story is dual.

Here's my problem - I can only see these definitions are equivalent in $\mathsf{Set}$, so for toposes - otherwise I don't know how to move between these descriptions.

So my question is - in what generality are these approaches to the definitions equivalent?